# Is there a way to commit assets that are used in website to GitHub?

Tags: github

Currently, when I push my website to GitHub and then download it, all the assets that are used in the website are missing. Is that meant to happen?

I've tried both cloning it and downloading it as ZIP. I don't see the assets on GitHub, only the code. Also I'm not sure if it matters, but I'm using Laravel as my framework.

Comment: Do you see the pushed files on GitHub? How do you download it?

Comment: I've tried both cloning it and downloading it as ZIP. I don't see assets on GitHub, only code. Also I'm not sure if it matters but I'm using Laravel as my framework.

Comment: Then I think you should check what's in your `.gitignore` file, maybe your assets are listed in it so they don't get committed.

Comment: Ah yes, seems like that is the case. Add it as answer so I can pick it as correct answer :) .

Comment: Glad I could help! I've added it as answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your feedback in the comments, your assets are not pushed to GitHub. This can happen when these files/directories are listed in your [`.gitignore` file](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

For example, if your assets are in `assets` directory and `.gitignore` contains a line like `assets/`, then your assets will not be tracked, committed, nor pushed to GitHub.

So you should check what's in your `.gitignore` and delete any line from it which points to your assets. Then add your files, commit and push.